# Fix 'no-sound' issue for game family-farm

Tags: sound, games, libraries

I have played the family-farm demo game for few days and then I bought the game through the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound disappeared when I installed the full game. I checked in the installation folder `/usr/lib/familyfarm` and I compared it to the demo folder and I see there is two library files missing:

1. libasound.so
2. libCg.so

After copiyng both files in the installation folder, sound now works. You will need root permissions to copy files into `/usr/lib/familyfarm`. Hope it may help someone.

*Using Ubuntu Studio 12.04 (Xubuntu)
Xfce 4.8*